# Не приходят пуши в открытое приложение

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messages

Есть служба которая должна отвечать за прием сообщений в активном приложении

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

}
private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    Uri defaultSoundUri=     RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round))
            .setContentTitle(this.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}}
```

В манифесте прописано

```
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Но при отправке пуша приложение на реальном устройстве его не показывает, хотя в эмуляторе всё работает.

Comment: Причин может масса, надо от вас дополнительно: - версия SDK + на каком устройстве запускаете, - пришел ли токен на сервер или подписка на топик, - доходит ли сообщение для клиента (залогируйте), - состояние устройства (подключен к питанию, есть ли сеть), и т.д.